# Как повернуть и наклонить блок

Tags: css, html5, css3

Помогите сверстать как на картинке:

[image: joxi.ru/zANyZXdU51eE29]

Нужно как-то наклонить и развернуть блок, скруглить края, а снизу добавить нечто, не знаю как это назвать, чтобы блок смотрелся объемным. И тень падала от этого блока.

Буду очень благодарен за информацию, примеры. Может кто-то уже делал нечто подобное.
Что самое интересное - это должно стать частью карусели.
За любые наводки буду весьма признателен.

Answer (score 2):

Что-то вроде...
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYMjra
Вот с реализацией конкретно этой части ещё нужно подумать =)
[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 0):

Вы все правильно написали, вам необходимо с помощью css сделать следующее:

1. повернуть блок
2. скруглить края
3. добавить тень

Ищите это все по отдельности. Как скруглить края - самое простое, как повернуть и добавить тень, если сильны в английском, можете посмотреть здесь [Rotated Images with CSS3 - grabduck.com](http://grabduck.com/search?q=css%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C&doc=12445,12444)